# Install custom Enterprise iOS apps on iPhone without trust pop-up message

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, enterprise

I have created a custom Enterprise iOS App and we want it push to our customers from our private links , but when the user are installing the app they are getting Trust pop Message due to which they have to follow the complex process of going to **Setting --> General -->  Device Management** and then trust our app from there.

Can we have some alternative where we can disable this message . We cant go with App store way.

Even going with Official MDM will be too tedious for the End User ,

Is there we can do avoid that trust message or decrease the number of steps atleast to trust that application .

**We are also trying to Open Device Management under General from Settings App directly from our website . IS it possible top open from our web page ?**

Any help or views is highly Appreciated .